# get value cell using first column name in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

This my data in excel file...

[image]

How to read all data in excel file using first column?

This my controller..

```
$excelreader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$loadexcel = $excelreader->load('assets/excel/'.$name);
$sheet = $loadexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true ,true);
```

This my view...

```
<?php foreach($sheet as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $row['A'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['B'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['C'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['D'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Desire view...

```
<?php foreach($sheet as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $row['NO'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['Name'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['Address'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['Phone Number'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, it's a sheet so you always use A, B,C, D... but you could use constant or something similar to do something like $row[ADDRESS]

Comment: Short answer, not likely. The header row is just that, a header row. Cells in a spreadsheet are addressed by their column and row. Are you having trouble using the column names in your output?

Answer (score 0):

**I think** you can not do that.
But you can do it if the column has the same name.
 it is necessary to rename in excel